# laravel - datetimepicker not working in loop

Tags: laravel

I show data in table with foreach and for each data I open a modal in the table. inside this model there is a datetimepicker. When I open the first modal, the datetimepicker works perfectly, but when close that modal and open another modal, the datetimepciker doesn't work. Where am I missing?

**Button to trigger modal**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart{{$result->orderId}}" class="orderNumber" >{{$result->orderNumber}}</a>
```

**Modal**

```
.
.
.
<div class="card-body collapse show" id="accordion4">
<form action="{{route('create-label')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label class="control-label" for="WeightLbs">Ship Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="reservationdate"  data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" name="shipDate" id="shipDate" class="form-control datetimepicker-input inputs" data-target="#reservationdate">
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#reservationdate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer mt-3" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>                          
</form>
</div>
.
.
.
```

**jQuery Script**

```
$(function () {
  $('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
  minDate: new Date(),
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify each date picker as a different element and which you can denote using flexible id to the element like:

```
. reservationdate_1 or reservationdate1
. reservationdate_2 or reservationdate1
. reservationdate_3 or reservationdate3
```

and bind the date picker to trigger accordingly.Keep the same class for the element i.e. `datepicker` as it will define the behaviour of element.

Right now you are using loop and using same id so it will not pick the other elements and will only refer to first element with id.Try it with this solution and see if you can get the result you want to achieve. You just have to render multiple elements with different id to identify them as different elements.

Have a great day.Hope this helps.

Example for multiple ids:

```
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
 <input  id="reservationdate_{{$key}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Something like this

Comment: what you said sounds very logical, but I don't know how to define a different id for each datetimepicker in the loop

Comment: Ok no problem let share an example

Comment: so how can i define it in jQuery or is there no need to define it in jQuery?

Comment: Are you creating datepicker on blade or dynamically through jquery. If you are creating whole content through jQuery also even then you can create this flow through js iteration or loop and using string concatination.

Comment: I'm creating it in blade as you said, but don't I have to define it in jQuery for each datetimepicker id?

Comment: Yes, then you can directly create in blade.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a `datepicker` class in your div and loop through it with an .each callback :

**Your modal** :

```
<div class="input-group-append datepicker" data-target="#reservationdate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery script** :

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: not working still same.